# How to get person data using Freebase API?

Tags: api, freebase

After 30 mins of reading Freebase Wiki, still can't figure out how to extact person data from their API. I have person unique identifier ("/m/01vwllw") and want to extract all infos about that person (address, birthdate, etc). 
Any hint will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/mqlread?query={%22type%22:%22/people/person%22%2C%22id%22:%22/m/01vwllw%22%2C%22name%22:null%2C%22date_of_birth%22:null}

Extend as appropriate for the additional facts that you want to know.

A more readable version of the query is:

```
{"id":"/m/01vw11w",
"type":"/people/person",
"name":null,
"date_of_birth":null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Topic API](http://wiki.freebase.com/wiki/Topic_API) is also a good way to get all the information about a person. We're working on releasing a new version of the Topic API soon.

Comment: I might argue that something about to be replaced by a "new version" shouldn't be described as a "good way" to do anything.  

I recently looking at Topic API for my own project, but don't want to have to re-implement my code when this old one is deprecated "soon" :(

Comment: Fair point. I just wanted to let donkeykong know that this is a use case that we're working on and that even though the current topic API is listed as beta we'll be releasing something very similar as a stable API next year.

Comment: The Topic API page has moved to http://developers.google.com/freebase/v1/topic-overview

Comment: @TextGeek invalid link